# r parser translating symbol_function_call as a symbol

Tags: r, parsing

If I parse `do.call(what=knitr::kable,args=args)`  the function `kable` in `do.call` is parsed to as a `SYMBOL` and not as a `SYMBOL_FUNCTION_CALL`.

Why shouldn't it be the later?

```
tf <- tempfile()
cat('do.call(knitr::kable,args=args)',file = tf)
parsed <- utils::getParseData(parse(tf))
knitr::kable(parsed)
```

`|   | line1| col1| line2| col2| id| parent|token                |terminal |text    |
|:--|-----:|----:|-----:|----:|--:|------:|:--------------------|:--------|:-------|
|18 |     1|    1|     1|   31| 18|      0|expr                 |FALSE    |        |
|1  |     1|    1|     1|    7|  1|      3|SYMBOL_FUNCTION_CALL |TRUE     |do.call |
|3  |     1|    1|     1|    7|  3|     18|expr                 |FALSE    |        |
|2  |     1|    8|     1|    8|  2|     18|'('                  |TRUE     |(       |
|7  |     1|    9|     1|   20|  7|     18|expr                 |FALSE    |        |
|4  |     1|    9|     1|   13|  4|      7|SYMBOL_PACKAGE       |TRUE     |knitr   |
|5  |     1|   14|     1|   15|  5|      7|NS_GET               |TRUE     |::      |
|6  |     1|   16|     1|   20|  6|      7|SYMBOL               |TRUE     |kable   |
|8  |     1|   21|     1|   21|  8|     18|','                  |TRUE     |,       |
|11 |     1|   22|     1|   25| 11|     18|SYMBOL_SUB           |TRUE     |args    |
|12 |     1|   26|     1|   26| 12|     18|EQ_SUB               |TRUE     |=       |
|13 |     1|   27|     1|   30| 13|     15|SYMBOL               |TRUE     |args    |
|15 |     1|   27|     1|   30| 15|     18|expr                 |FALSE    |        |
|14 |     1|   31|     1|   31| 14|     18|')'                  |TRUE     |)       |`

Answer (score 0):

If you just have `ktable` its a symbol. That symbol could point to a function or a value. It's not clear until you actually evaluate it what it is.

However if you have `ktable()`, it's clear that you expect `ktable` to be a function and that you are calling it.

The `do.call` obscures the parser's ability to recognize that you are trying to call a function and that intention isn't realized till run-time.

Things can get funny if you do something like

```
sum <- 5
sum
# [1] 5
sum(1:3)
# [1] 6
```

Here `sum` is behaving both like a regular variable and a function. We've actually created a shadow variable in our global environment that masks the `sum` function from `base`. But because the parse treats `sum` and `sum()` differently we can still get at both meanings.

Comment: so no way around this? is it a bug?

Comment: It's not a bug. This is the correct way to parse that code. If you have a different definition of what a parser should do, then you can write your own. It's unclear why exactly you think this is a problem.

Comment: i have a script that works off the parser and filters out `symbol_function_call`'s , and it is ignoring that function because the parser is misreading the call as a `symbol`.

Comment: Well, then that's really just a unfortunate design decision. It's not really the parser's fault. You can add a special case for `do.call` if that's the only thing you are trying to catch. Code can also run functions by using `eval(parse())` which a parser would not catch either. Since R allows meta-programming, you can "hide" function calls in many different ways. `getParseData` is working exactly as it should in this case.